# publication without sponsor's permission whether will cause illegal problem

Tags: publications, phd

My work is currently sponsored by a company, but i did not sign any type of agreement. Our sponsor always want better results, which had lead us to have no publications record, although our result is quite new. We do not really want our work to go unpublished, but we also worried if we submit our work without the company's approval, we may have illegal problems. Our adviser depends on our sponsor which is not really an option to talk to her. Any advise? we kind of want to submit to a journal and just try.

Comment: Are you asking us whether the terms of the sponsorship gives you ownership of the intellectual property and/or freedom to publish without getting approval from them? *We* can't possibly know that.

Comment: @ff524's questions and, in addition: is the sponsor interested at all in publication? Do they have a track record of previously supported published results?

Comment: We want to publish the work without approval from them. We've attempted to send them the work, but it stagnates on their desk. We want to know if their would be legal consequences to submit to a journal without their approval.

Comment: Sorry, nobody can answer this without knowing the terms of the sponsorship. If they own the intellectual property you produce then sure, there can be legal problems. If the contract they have with your advisor requires approval in publications, then yes, there could be legal problems. But we don't know those terms so we can't say.

Comment: Thanks all. Yeah sounds like it may cause legal problems. Sad PhD life.

Comment: Just don't do that! The answer most probably is written in the contract and regulations of the department. Perhaps a little patience is advisable. If the sponsor is in the same location and not so far away, probably just arrange a meeting face to face, most e-mails are lost in the inbox.